# Restrict double tap Zoom Out in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

All,

In my project i am displaying a SVG image in UIWebview, I want to zoom, I am able to do that but when i tap two times unexpectedly, The complete view is Zoom Out, How can i do that? How can we restrict the zoom Out, Please help me out

Comment: try this `_webView.scalesPageToFit = NO; _webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all the touch events then disable `UserInteractionEnabled` property. For specific touch event, override existing tap events by adding `UIGestureRecognizer` over particular view, for your case - `UIWebView` instance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   .....
   .....

   UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTapOnWebView:)];
   [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2]; // 2 for double tap event
   [doubleTap setDelegate:self]; // Add the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> protocol
   [self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
} 
- (void)handleDoubleTapOnWebView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
   //Do nothing.
}
```

Hope this helps.